# How do I fix the 'int' object has no attribute 'move' error when trying to allow the user to press the arrow keys to move an image?

Tags: python, tkinter, move

There is a part in my program where the user needs to move an image resembling their character by pressing the arrow keys or the 'wasd' keys. I have tried many ways to fix my code but it still produces the AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'move'.
This is a section of my code:

```
#functions to move the player image
def left(event):
    level1.move(playerImage, -10, 0)
    
def right(event):
    level1.move(playerImage, 10, 0)
    
def up(event):
    level1.move(playerImage, 0, -10)

def down(event):
    level1.move(playerImage, 0, 10)
    
    
#function to open the level 1 page
def level1():
    
    #close levelSelection page and open level1 page
    root3.destroy()
    root4 = Tk()
    
    root4.bind("<a>", left)
    root4.bind("<d>", right)
    root4.bind("<w>", up)
    root4.bind("<s>", down)
    root4.bind('<Left>', left)
    root4.bind('<Right>', right)
    root4.bind('<Up>', up)
    root4.bind('<Down>', down)
    
    #create a canvas for the level1 and put it into the root
    level1 = Canvas(root4, height = 1500, width = 2000, bg = 'LightBlue3')
    level1.pack()
    
    #bring player image onto canvas
    player = PhotoImage(file = 'Player.png')
    playerImage = level1.create_image(425, 1200, image = player)
    
    mainloop()#end level1 page
```

Comment: You have 2 definitions of what `level1` is. One of them is a function (`def level1()`) and the other one is a tkinter canvas (`level1 = Canvas(...)`). When you have variable name clashes like that a lot of problems can happen

Comment: Also I think you are using the variable `level1` for something else as well like `level1 = <tkinter.Canvas>.create_image(...)` which setts `level1` as an `int` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't move canvas objects by calling `move` on the object id, you do it by calling `move` on the canvas and passing in the object id.

```
level1.move(playerImage, 10, 0)
```

Though in your case it won't work either since `level1` is a function and also a local variable, and `playerImage` is also a local variable. You need to save the identifiers of the objects you move in a global variable (or use classes, or canvas tags), and you shouldn't be using the same name for both a function and a variable.

For example:

```
def left(event):
    level1_canvas.move(playerImage_id, -10, 0)

def level1():
    global level1_canvas, player1_id
    ...
    level1_canvas = Canvas(root4, height = 1500, width = 2000, bg = 'LightBlue3')
    ...
    player1_id = level1_canvas.create_image(...)
```

Though, if you are going to be creating multiple levels and/or multiple players it would be much better to use classes rather than global variables. Regardless, the root of your problem is that you're not using the `move` method properly.